# support.v7.app.AlertDialog throws NullPointerException on dismiss

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-appcompat

I updated `AppCompat` to the newly released revision `22.1.0` and changed my `AlertDialog` to `support.v7.app.AlertDialog`. But on a Lollipop device, it throws the following exception on `dismissDialog()`.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException:   attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
  at android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar.getDecorToolbar(WindowDecorActionBar.java:248)
  at android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar.init(WindowDecorActionBar.java:201)
  at android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar.<init>(WindowDecorActionBar.java:184)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDeleg  ateImplV7.cre  ateSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:176)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.getSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:85)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onStop(AppCompatDeleg  ateImplV7.java:221)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.onStop(AppCompatDialog.java:108)
  at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:438)
  at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:414)
  at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:157)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5834)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
```

How do I fix it?

(Lower-version devices seems to work well. This just happens in Lollipop)

**+**
I don't call `dismiss()` explicitly in my code. The dialog throws the exception when it is dismissed by back-button or positive/negative button.

**++** Here is my code that uses v7.app.AlertDialog. Thank you.

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.text.TextUtils;

public class SimpleYesNoFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public interface OnConfirmListner {
        public void onConfirm();
    }

    public static SimpleYesNoFragment newInstance(String title, String message) {
        SimpleYesNoFragment fragment = new SimpleYesNoFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title", title);
        args.putString("message", message);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    private OnConfirmListner mListener;

    public void setOnConfirmListener(OnConfirmListner l) {
        mListener = l;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder b=  new  AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if(mListener != null) {
                    mListener.onConfirm();
                }
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });

        Bundle args = getArguments();
        String title = args.getString("title",null);
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(title)) {
            b.setTitle(title);
        }
        String message = args.getString("message",null);
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(message)) {
            b.setMessage(message);
        }

        return b.create();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you get the reference of the dialog on which you called the `dismiss()` method? If you post a snippet of your code, it would be easier to help

Comment: Please post your code. We can't answer your question without it.

Comment: @KamranAhmed I added the last line in the question

Comment: @Sufian the exception is not thrown from my code. Please see the last line of the question I've just added

Comment: @hoonj can't you post the code ?

Comment: @maveň i've just added my code. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

By chance I've noticed that my project has `values-v21/themes.xml` and it applies `android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog.Alert` to the `support.v7.app.AlertDialog`. This caused the weird bug.

Using a proper AppCompat Theme, such as `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert`, to the `support.v7.app.AlertDialog` solved the problem. Thanks to everyone for helping me out.

Comment: I had the same problem and your answer helped me to discover which attribute i had to change to avoid the problem. Simply set the following attribute on your dialog's style and the problem is gone:

<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>