# The Activity's LayoutInflater already has a Factory installed so we can not install AppCompat's

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I'm using AppCompat library (com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0) in my app. I created an ActionBar in a fragment. When I click in a menu item it shows an Alert Dialog. Here is my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_new:
            showFilterDialog();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_send:
            new sendInventoryTask().execute();
            return true;           
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And my showInventoryDialog method:

```
private void showFilterInventoryDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    LayoutInflater inflater= getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_filter_inventory,null);
    alert.setView(v);
    alert.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.filters));
    alert.setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.filter), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // TODO
        }

    });

    alert.setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.cancel), null);
    alert.show();
}
```

Everything works fine, but when I click on menu item, the logcat shows me an error:

> I/AppCompatDelegate﹕ The Activity's LayoutInflater already has a Factory installed so we can not install AppCompat's

How to solve this?

Comment: What class is extended by your activity class?

Comment: MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are required to use the themed context in this case, i.e. instead of

> new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

you have to do

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
```

Besides, you also need to follow the parent theme and windowActionBar tip given here - [support.v7.app.AlertDialog throws NullPointerException on dismiss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29815115/support-v7-app-alertdialog-throws-nullpointerexception-on-dismiss)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with latest AppCompat on L or M devices.

Comment: This didn't have any effect, I still get the logcat message.

Answer (score 7):

From what I can tell, appcompat 23.1.1 calls `installViewFactory()` in `AppCompatDelegateImplV7` every time you show a dialog created by `AlertDialog.Builder`.

Call Stack:

> at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.installViewFactory(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:970)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.onCreate(AppCompatDialog.java:58)
>   at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:239)
>   at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:361) at
>   android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:262) at
>   android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:902)

```
    @Override
    public void installViewFactory() {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        if (layoutInflater.getFactory() == null) {
            LayoutInflaterCompat.setFactory(layoutInflater, this);
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "The Activity's LayoutInflater already has a Factory installed"
                    + " so we can not install AppCompat's");
        }
    }
```

As you can see, once the factory is already set it just logs the informational message.  It seems pretty safe to ignore, but it can get annoying when it fills up your logs.

Answer (score 0):

Solution - The error "The Activity's LayoutInflater already has a Factory installed so we can not install AppCompat's" could also be due to incorrect code. In my case the code was calling "super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)" twice (code error) and once the duplicate call was removed the error was resolved.

This is my error log:

```
02-29 04:54:40.706 4417-4417/com.projects.ajay.example2 I/AppCompatDelegate: The Activity's LayoutInflater already has a Factory installed so we can not install AppCompat's
02-29 04:54:40.709 4417-4417/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-29 04:54:40.715 4417-4417/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.projects.ajay.example2, PID: 4417
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.projects.ajay.example2/com.projects.ajay.example2.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already attached
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5351)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already attached
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachController(FragmentManager.java:2025)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.attachHost(FragmentController.java:95)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:276)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:61)
    at com.projects.ajay.example2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6020)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5351) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703) 
02-29 04:54:40.727 4417-4417/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 4417 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_filter_inventory,null);
```

to

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_filter_inventory,null,false);
```

In case of inflating a Dialog, we don't want it to attach to the specified ViewGroup (== null).

This could help.

**Second try**

The info-log is thrown by the following code in `AppCompatDelegateImplV7`:

```
@Override
public void installViewFactory() {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    if (layoutInflater.getFactory() == null) {
        LayoutInflaterCompat.setFactory(layoutInflater, this);
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "The Activity's LayoutInflater already has a Factory installed"
                + " so we can not install AppCompat's");
    }
}
```

Could it be you installed a Factory somewere earlier in your code?

Comment: I made the change but still the same

Comment: Are you using the standard or v7 version of AlertDialog?

Comment: I'm importing android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog