# AlertDialog not displaying

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-appcompat

I have an alert dialog that is not displaying. I've read through many other posts here on this issue, and followed all of the suggested advice, yet still not seeing anything.

I am checking if there is an available network connection, and if not, displaying an AlertDialog to prompt the user to connect to WIFI.

In my logging, it correctly shows that no connection is available, and that it is about to show the AlertDialog, but then nothing is visible.

```
public class PopulateDataActivity extends BaseActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    populateData();
}

void populateData() {
    boolean hasConnection = Utility.isNetworkAvailable(this);
    if(!hasConnection){
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "No connection.");
        showConnectDialog(this);
    }
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Trying to populate languages");
    //get data from server
}
}

abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public void showConnectDialog(Context context)
{
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Showing connection dialog.");
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.connect_to_internet);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.connect_yes_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.connect_no_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
}
```

Log output:

```
D/PopulateDataActivity No connection.
D/BaseActivity﹕ Showing connection dialog.
I/AppCompatDelegate﹕ The Activity's LayoutInflater already has a Factory installed so we can not install AppCompat's
D/PopulateDataActivity Trying to populate languages
```

Is that AppCompat the issue here, or am I missing something else?

Because the dialog is not displayed, the activity then just continues on and tries to make the data connection, which then throws an exception.

I have now found that when it continues on in the execution, a later AlertDialog is shown when the data retrieval is unsuccessful. This displays fine, and I can see that the first one (the ConnectDialog referenced here) has been displayed beneath it, but I never can actually reach it.

This issue seems to be related: [The Activity's LayoutInflater already has a Factory installed so we can not install AppCompat's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31677552/the-activitys-layoutinflater-already-has-a-factory-installed-so-we-can-not-inst%5D)

Comment: Try to extend Activity, if that works then yes, AppCompat is the issue

Comment: @Blackbelt It's crashing when the exception is thrown because there is no network connection available. The AlertDialog itself is not crashing it though.

Comment: @Marcus To extend Activity instead, I'd have to make changes to very other activity, as they all then extend this BaseActivity - presumably other activities may need to prompt for a network connection as well.

Comment: What version of support:appcompat are you using?

Comment: Unfortunately I tested against `v7:22.2.0` and got no errors.

Comment: This seems to be the same issue without a solution: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31677552/the-activitys-layoutinflater-already-has-a-factory-installed-so-we-can-not-inst]

Comment: did you solved the issue .I am facing the same issue now .Kindly help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using AppCompat v7:22.1.0. I created a small app to try to isolate the issue and could not until I applied the same style as my main app. The culprid was when I set my own theme to alert dialogs using the 'alertDialogTheme' attribute. In this particular activity, I did not need to change the style from the default. So I created a new theme that sets the 'alertDialogTheme' attribute back the default value and applied the theme to the activity.

```
<item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert</item>
```

This is not a full solution but I hope it helps someone get to the end of it.

Note: My alert dialog does not have a button. Adding a button made the issue go away even with the custom theme.