# Push Notification throwing error on custom layout

Tags: android, notifications

I get the following error for whatever reason i don't know.

`AppCompatDelegate: The Activity's LayoutInflater already has a Factory installed so we can not install AppCompat`

```
  RemoteViews mContentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),R.layout.custom_layout);
  mContentView.setTextViewText(R.id.notiftitle, message); 
  Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(
                getApplicationContext()).setContent(mContentView).
                setAutoCancel(true).setContentIntent(pIntent).setSound(alertSound).
                setContentTitle(getResources()
               .getString(R.string.app_name)).getNotification();
        // Remove the notification on click
        // notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        Random r = new Random();
        int i1 = r.nextInt(100000000 - 0) + 0;
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(i1, notification);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31677552/the-activitys-layoutinflater-already-has-a-factory-installed-so-we-can-not-inst

Comment: Try NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this) instead of Notification and getNotifications