# ImageView inside AlertDialog not displaying

Tags: android, kotlin

Initially, I had a dialog set with transparent background with `dialog.window?.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent)`. After removing this and trying several approaches, it seems that the ImageView still fails to show. Here are the approaches I've tried so far:

1. Making a full screen dialog with `android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen` but this gives just a black background covering the entire screen.
2. Adding background both in my root view in my dialog layout and/or in ImageView. This just gives me an empty view.

Also, I'm logging the image URL that I'm receiving and it is giving me the correct url. I even tried hardcoding the right url and it's still giving me same result. BUT, when I set the image directly with `android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"`, it shows the image.

Here is my **DialogHelper** class:

```
class DialogHelper(private val context: Context) {

    lateinit var dialogView: View
    lateinit var dialog: AlertDialog

    fun showMediaDialog(
        photoUrl: String?,
        videoUrl: String?
    ) {
        createFullScreenDialog(R.layout.dialog_media_viewer)
        if (photoUrl != null) {
            dialogView.dialog_post_photo.instaVisible()
            // having problems here:
            Glide.with(context)
                .load(photoUrl)
                .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
                .into(dialogView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.dialog_post_photo))
        } else {
            // this section is working and the views are behaving as expected
            dialogView.dialog_post_photo.instaGone()
            dialogView.dialog_post_video.instaVisible()
            dialogView.dialog_video_progress.instaVisible()
            val exoPlayerHelper = ExoPlayerHelper(
                playerView = dialogView.dialog_post_video,
                onError = {
                    dialogView.error_msg?.popShow()
                },
                onPlayerBuffer = { isBuffering ->
                    if (isBuffering) dialogView.dialog_video_progress?.popShow()
                    else dialogView.dialog_video_progress?.popHide()
                }
            )
            exoPlayerHelper.initializePlayer(videoUrl!!)
            dialog.setOnDismissListener {
                exoPlayerHelper.killPlayer()
            }
        }
        dialog.show()
    }

    // My first attempt
    fun createDialog(resourceId: Int, style: Int = R.style.DefaultDialogAnimation) {
        dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(context).create()
        dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(resourceId, null)
        dialog.setView(dialogView)
        dialog.window?.attributes?.windowAnimations = style
        dialog.window?.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent)
    }

    // Second attempt
    private fun createFullScreenDialog(resourceId: Int, style: Int = R.style.DefaultDialogAnimation) {
        dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(context, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen).create()
        dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(resourceId, null)
        dialog.setView(dialogView)
        dialog.window?.attributes?.windowAnimations = style
    }
}
```

And my **dialog_media_viewer.xml**:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                >

                <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
                        android:id="@+id/dialog_post_video"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        app:use_controller="false"
                        />

                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/error_msg"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="Could not play video at the moment."
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        />

                <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/dialog_video_progress"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        />

                <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/dialog_post_photo"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the logcat I receive when I click on the button that shows the dialog:

```
2019-12-16 01:37:48.707 30253-30253/com.devssocial.localodge D/TEST: IMAGE URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/localodge/o/posts%2FqRRZpFmoLLN5TFu9dEj5?alt=media&token=ed8cb341-d4e1-4330-8020-51fa46a9d341
2019-12-16 01:37:48.708 30253-30253/com.devssocial.localodge I/AppCompatDelegate: The Activity's LayoutInflater already has a Factory installed so we can not install AppCompat's
```

And my Glide version:

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
```

Comment: what is your requirement?

Comment: I need the ImageView to show. Right now my dialog is not displaying it

Comment: did you the check the url if its not empty and correct?

Comment: Yea. It is retrieving the right url. I'm certain because I'm displaying it in a fragment as well and the image is showing up. I'm also logging it and it's giving the right url.

Comment: comment transition from glide and then check

Comment: @Nik still not working D:

Comment: Is your other views visibility are gone while you are displaying image.. as you have added dialog_post_video and dialog_video_progress?

Comment: Yes. My intention was only to have `dialog_post_photo` visible while the rest are gone.

Comment: Can you share logcat?

Comment: try see link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31677552/the-activitys-layoutinflater-already-has-a-factory-installed-so-we-can-not-inst

Comment: please change this line dialogView.dialog_post_photo.instaVisible() to dialogView.dialog_post_photo.visibility=View.VISIBLE

Comment: @Quicklearner Hi. I tried but didn't work. `instaVisible` and `instaGone` are basically extension functions that I made that sets either `visibility = View.VISIBLE` or `visibility = View.GONE`. So it should have the same behavior.

Comment: @Christilyn Have you checked with 0dp height - width instead of match parent and set activity context in glide.

Comment: @Nik Although this didn't work, I was able to make it work by playing with the `ImageView`'s width and height thanks to your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that by setting the `ImageView`'s width and height to `wrap_content`, everything works as expected. So my final layout was:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                >

                <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
                        android:id="@+id/dialog_post_video"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        app:use_controller="false"
                        />

                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/error_msg"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="Could not play video at the moment."
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        />

                <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/dialog_video_progress"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        />

                <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/dialog_post_photo"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is a very strange behavior. Perhaps something to do with my **styles.xml**:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/AppTheme.Widget.TextView</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FeedbackDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/DefaultDialogAnimation</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DefaultDialogAnimation">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/scale</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_right</item>
    </style>

    <style name="HomeTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/AppTheme.Widget.TextView</item>

    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Fullscreen">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Widget.TextView" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.TextView">
        <item name="fontPath">fonts/Montserrat-Medium.ttf</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

</resources>
```